# Split a string using python slice or split method

Tags: pandas, split, slice

One of the columns in a pandas dataframe has a string like:
BANKNIFTY2330935500PE, FINNIFTY2330618050PE, NIFTY23DEC21000CE, TCS23MAR3000PE
The first of the string (all alphabets in caps) is security name like BANKNIFTY, FINNIFTY, NIFTY, TCS
The second part of the string holds the date like:23309, 23306, 23DEC, 23MAR
The next is the value: 35500, 18050, 21000, 21000, 3000
The last is the type: CE, PE

I tried this way:

````
      security = df.symbol.str[0:9]
      type = df.symbol.str[-2:]
      value = df.symbol.str[-7:-2]```
Can anyone suggest a better method of slicing or splitting the string into four parts?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str.extract` here with multiple capture groups:

```py
df[["security", "date", "value", "type"]] = df["col"].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+)(\d{5}|\d{2}[A-Z]{3})(\d+)([A-Z]+)')
```

The regex pattern used here says to match and capture:

- `([A-Z]+)` capture an all caps security name
- `(\d{5}|\d{2}[A-Z]{3})` capture a 5 digit date or DDMON
- `(\d+)` capture a value which is one or more digits
- `([A-Z]+)` capture an all caps type

Here is a working regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gZjY6/1).

Comment: Thank you. That's  quite a bit of learning for me.